# How to build good jumps?

Tags: mountain-bike

Not sure if this is the right place for this... But I'm wondering how I can make 'good' jumps. I've made a few using a 1 tonne digger.
 [image: Tabletop]
[image: another tabletop]

I had the tabletop with the pallet a gap at first but I made it a tabletop for more fun. They're okay to jump, but the problem is the landing is really soft and I've watered it, compacted it, done everything I can think of any it's still loose dirt?? 
So my question is how can I make reliable jumps?

Comment: What is wrong with a soft landing?  Would you rather land on cement?

Comment: @Blam the problem with a soft landing is that it's so soft that you sink in when you land...

Comment: Just let it weather and it will firm up.

Comment: @Blam I've done that for the last few weeks, it's rained recently and they've dried up and just gone soft again? should I wet it, compress it then let it dry?

Comment: Look for someone that does soil work in you area.  Soil differs a lot.  Who did did you get the digger from?  They should know a bit about soil in your area.  You can add lime to firm it up.

Comment: @Blam I'll try that. And the digger is mine. A guy comes in to do the neighbours gardens quite often so when he next comes I'll ask him - he knows a lot about the ground here.

Comment: If you've not seen this already... - http://www.pinkbike.com/forum/listcomments/?threadid=3110

Comment: I haven't built jumps, but wouldn't some structural elements firm the ramp up? For example a pile of logs, perpendicular to the rider line, then covered with 10cm of soil.

Comment: @Vorac we've done a jump like that, the problem is they aren't too solid and they're always quite soft but it does save a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably rent a [Wacker](http://www.wackerneuson.us/en/productgroups/listgroup/compaction.html) ( yes, that is the real name ) at a local construction equipment rental store. It is a tool that ground construction workers use. It is basically a really heavy steel plate that an engine sits on. The engine vibrates the whole machine and the weight and the vibration compact the ground very tightly.

You'd have to work in layers. Don't expect to compact the whole mound all at once. That is not the way it works.

The giant rollers on freeway construction sites do the same thing.

Comment: yeah I might do that.. I have fairly easy access to a roller but I think it would be too big. I'll look into a wacker :)

Answer (score 2):

If your landing is soft you should put some old carpet over it. This solution is not as good as having a completely packed landing and it's still soft (therefore more rolling resistance), but you can carry a lot more speed once you have landed. An added bonus of using carpet is that the soft landing will not be damaged as much by you landing on it.